# How to intentionally lock out AD service account for testing?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service-accounts

We are testing a service account notification job on windows task scheduler. The job will only be triggered if the Security Job Log shows an Event 4740.

The job is set-up fine. It's time to test.

Can someone tell me the simplest way to intentionally lock out a test service account? I have a slight idea that it could be done using bad passwords.

Comment: Have you looked into mocking the service? That way you create all the desired states and check your code copes with each without having to mess around with the real accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, Sir we have mocked a test account for the same purpose. Now I need to lock it intentionally.

Comment: If your code works with the mocked account it should work with the real account so there's no need to repeat the tests.

Comment: The code is just setup. I want to trigger the code by locking a test account.

Comment: You should be able to test that with mocks as well. Configure the code to use the mock, lock the mock account and then when the job runs it should fail with the appropriate error message.

Comment: You said "Lock the mock account ". My question is how do I lock the mock account?

Comment: Failed password attempts should lock the account but you would need to check what your domain policy is for that setting.